# SSL Certificate verify failed

Tags: linux, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am running a python application that uses Facebook Ads API to access Ads data. This is setup in Linux Red Hat Server.

The same application is running successfully in Windows but it's throwing the following error when run from the server:
[image]

Comment: One quick fix should be setting `verify` to `false`, like: `requests.get('https://apifacebooklalala.com', verify=False)`

Comment: Please check the CA for the certificate and verify it is there in your cacert. If not, you have to import the cert into your keystore.